# Parsing JSON to find value for key

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse json to find the value of a desired key. I am doing so recursively. If there is another, fast or more efficient way to do so, I am open

example json:

```
{  
   "data_version":"5",
   "application":{  
      "platform":"iPhone",
      "os":"iPhone OS",
      "locale":"en_US",
      "app_version":"unknown",
      "mobile":{  
         "device":"iPhone",
         "carrier":"Verizon",
      }
   },
   "event_header":{  
      "accept_language":"en-us",
      "topic_name":"mobile-clickstream",
      "server_timestamp":1416958459572,
      "version":"1.0"
   },
   "session":{  
      "properties":{  

      }
   },
   "event":{  
      "timestamp":1416958459185,
      "properties":{  
         "event_sequence_number":97
      }
   }
}
```

here is what I have so far

```
def json_scan(json_obj, key):
    result = None
    for element in json_obj:
        if str(element) == key:
            result = json_obj[element]
        else:
            if type(json_obj[element]) == DictType:
                json_scan(json_obj[element], key)
            elif type(json_obj[element]) == ListType:
                json_scan(element, key)
    return result
```

expected output:

```
>>> json_scan(json_obj, "timestamp")
1416958459185
```

As I go through the debugger, I am able to find the the desired value but the line `result = None` resets result to `None` and at the end of the method, the value I get is `None`. I'm not sure how to fix this. I tried removing the line but I get error because result is not preset to a value.

Comment: You need to *assign the recursive call* - e.g. `result = json_scan(element, key)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe i tried this but the line still resets result to None

Comment: What do you mean *"the line"*? You shouldn't need `result = None` at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I removed the line `result = None` and added the adjustments you suggested for the recursive calls (                `result = json_scan(json_obj[element], key)` and `result = json_scan(element, key))` but I am getting the local variable "result" referenced before assignment error

Comment: In that case, `for element in json_obj:` isn't happening in one of the calls (whatever `json_obj` is is empty), hence you reach `return result` before it gets assigned.

Comment: @jonrsharpe making adjustments to the code. Good catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using json library in order to parse the json file (some commas should be deleted) and using native dict types :

```
def json_scan(json_obj, key):
    d = json.loads(json_obj)

    def _(dictobj, lookup):
        if lookup in dictobj.keys():
            return dictobj[lookup]
        else:
            for sub_dictobj in [d for d in dictobj.values() if type(d) == DictType]:
                result = _(sub_dictobj, lookup)
                if result:
                    return result
            return None

    return _(d, key)
```

A more complete version :

```
def json_scan(json_obj, key):
    d = json.loads(json_obj)

    def _(dictobj, lookup):
        if lookup in dictobj.keys():
            return dictobj[lookup]
        else:
            for sub_dictobj in [d for d in dictobj.values() if type(d) == DictType]:
                result = _(sub_dictobj, lookup)
                if result:
                    return result

            # if objects in dictobj.values() are lists, go through them
            for listobject in [l for l in dictobj.values() if type(d) == list]:
                for sub_dictobj in [d for d in listobject if type(d) == DictType]:
                    result = _(sub_dictobj, lookup)
                    if result:
                        return result
            return None

    return _(d, key)
```

EDIT (2015/04/25):

After looking @ PyCon 2015 videos, I came across dict_digger :

http://jtushman.github.io/blog/2013/11/06/dict-digger/ 
https://github.com/jtushman/dict_digger

It comes with tests...

Comment: This was an excellent solution. However, it does not take consideration when the `key` is in a dictionary within a list.
`{"events":
   [
    { 
     "network_type":"unknown",
     "properties":
      {
       "DeviceOsVersion":"iopi-iOS-8.1",
       "DeviceModel":"iopi-iPhone Simulator",
       "AppVersion":"iopi-iPhone-7.4b1 (lib 7.4b1)"},
       "timestamp":1416848861703
      }
   ],
    "session":
     {
      "properties":{}
     }
  }`

Comment: You're right ! Adding a test for list type to support deeper search resolves the limitation.

Answer (score 1):

You should return result from inside your if statement.  So, your code would be:

```
def json_scan(json_obj, key):
    for element in json_obj:
        if str(element) == key:
            result = json_obj[element]
            return result
        else:
            if type(json_obj[element]) == DictType:
                json_scan(json_obj[element], key)
            elif type(json_obj[element]) == ListType:
                json_scan(element, key)
    return None
```

That way if you find the result, it'll return it immediately instead of resetting it to None.  If it doesn't find it, it'll still return None at the end.

Comment: It finds the key but that line still resets results to None

Comment: What if you remove result = None and only assign result inside of your if statement?  See my edit.

Comment: @Liondancer Does it still return `None` if you replace `json_scan(...)` in ekrah's code with `return json_scan(...)`?

Comment: @tepples I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment` it is due to the empty dictionaries in my JSON

Comment: You actually don't really need result.  Just `return json_obj[element]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't assign the recursive calls to result:

```
def json_scan(json_obj, key):
    result = None
    for element in json_obj:
        if str(element) == key:
            result = json_obj[element]
        else:
            if type(json_obj[element]) == DictType:
                result = json_scan(json_obj[element], key)
            elif type(json_obj[element]) == ListType:
                result = json_scan(element, key)
    return result
```

Another problem is that your scan doesn't work for lists - `json_obj[element]` is only going to work for dicts - but since your data doesn't have lists, its working for now. You should remove list processing completely (unless you really have lists, then the algorithm needs to change).